# Where to start with physics?

Tags: physics

So I already have a degree in math and am working on a masters, but I’ve taken no physics since grade 12, and I think it would be really interesting. I’m not trying to get an official degree, I’m just wondering if math people might have suggestions about what I can read that won’t be too boring because I have an advanced math knowledge, but won’t be too complicated because I have a low level understanding of physics. Anybody have suggestions? Specifically I’m looking for the best path to get into quantum theory I think.

Thanks in advance!

Note: I realize this is the math stack exchange, not physics, but as a mathematician I wanted a mathematicians perspective

Comment: You do know other people visit this site than mathematicians?

Comment: You could probably handle *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics* by Arnol'd. I'd also recommend *Principles of Quantum Mechanics* by Shankar. Both are high level enough so you won't be bored, but start from something approximating the beginning.

Comment: A lot of people may recommend mathematical physics books like symplectic geometry, GR, etc, but I believe this is the wrong approach if you truly have no experience with physics. I recommend "Physics for mathematicians" by Spivak. It really covers the basics regarding terminology and intuition. A mathematical physics book will be pretty useless to you if you don't have a grasp of physical concepts like energy or a flux or dimensional analysis beyond just their strict mathematical definitions.

Comment: Emil well technically “mathematician” has no professional meaning I just expected this to be the area that math oriented people would respond in. Your comment was unnecessary and useless... everyone else thanks for the suggestions! I’ll check those books out for sure, if I find any to be particularly best I’ll give an update on which one

Comment: That is an odd definition you are using.

Comment: You might find the recent set of videos by Prof. Sean Carroll a good overview.  It is a pretty thorough survey of modern physics, including quantum theory, general relativity, with a good amount of mathematical discussion (topology, group theory, etc.) integrated, and accessible to the non-physicist audience:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HI09kat_GeI&list=PLrxfgDEc2NxZJcWcrxH3jyjUUrJlnoyzX  I hope this helps.